# What is N+できる grammar?

Tags: grammar, potential-form

Consider the following two sentences.

A:　僕は左と右が区別できない。

B:　僕は左と右を区別することができない。

I often see B but just know A now.

How can A be possible? What kind of grammar is A?

---

The following sentence (from the [Tanaka Corpus](http://www.edrdg.org/wiki/index.php/Tanaka_Corpus)) inspired me to ask this question:

> その[坊や]{ぼうや}はツバメとスズメが[区別]{くべつ}できない。
>   The boy can't tell a swallow from a sparrow.

Comment: A is simply wrong. People will understand what you mean, but it's grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @sonigo What is your basis for this claim?

Comment: Consider できる as the potential form of する、 and 区別する → 区別できる makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct. できる means exactly the same thing as することができる. You can treat it as a special potential form of する.

So it's not that できる is being attached to a noun, it's that it is taking the place of する in a する verb.

Here are a couple more examples:

```
この部屋はうるさくて勉強できない。（勉強することができない）

明日の予約が確認できた。（予約を確認することができた）
```

Note that it's most common to mark the thing that you can do with が rather than を because, like potential forms in general, できる really means that such-and-such "is doable." You'll see を sometimes but you can consider が the the traditionally correct way to phrase it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: 「僕は納豆を食べられない。」と「僕は納豆が食べられない。」とどちらが正しいでしょうか。

Comment: As I mentioned, I think most people would consider the second sentence to be the most "correct," which I put in quotation marks because in real life, modern native speakers do mark objects with 'wo' sometimes, if it is a verb that normally takes 'wo.' So my advice is, prefer the second, but be prepared to hear the first as well.