# Is the verb 「できる」also transitive verb?

Tags: grammar, verbs

As I know, the verb can only be intransitive verb but when I found the following sentence, I'm not sure if it can be both types.

Homeメニューや内蔵ソフトで、機能やソフトの追加があるときに本体の更新を行うと、本体を最新の状態に**できます**。

What does it mean in this sentence? I guessed it would be 'to make the console to be in the latest version'.

Comment: It looks to me like slightly sloppy writing, omitting a bit: 本体を最新の状態に**することが**できます。

Comment: These threads might be of help: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33698/9831 ・ http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29573/9831

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of the できる as the potential form of する.

> AをBにする -- make/keep A B; change/turn A to B
>   AをBにできる -- can make/keep A B; can change/turn A to B

The できる can be rephrased as することができる.